# COTS T1 over Ethernet/IP solution?

Tags: ip, ethernet

I am looking into a low cost solution to run a T1 link over ethernet, I found this one:

http://www.rad-direct.com/Product-TDMoverIP-Gateway-IPMUX11.htm

$1500 for the link.  Anoyne else have other solutions that will be as reliable/cheaper/etc? Anyone ever use this model?

Comment: Do you mean a PRI T1 (for voice)?  Otherwise, why would you run a data T1 over ethernet.  I don't see the point.

Comment: That is correct, it is to connect two PBX systems.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the Digium cards before:

http://store.digium.com/productview.php?product_code=TE121B

(for example)

Take a look around; those are mostly intended to be used with Asterisk, but perhaps they will serve your needs as well.